# Get items from List A where Id is common in both List A and List B and counter of that Id is more than 1 in List A or List B

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I was looking to get items from ListA, where the value of Id is same in both of the lists, and the count of Id must be more than 1 in list A or list B

```
var items = itemsA.Where(x => itemsB.Select(y => y.Id == x.Id).Count() > 1);
```

This gives me the result where same Ids in itemsB is more then 1, I want to use a or condition to check for the same counter in itemsA

```
Eg 1:
ListA=[{"id"=1,"name="abc"},{"id=1, "name"="def"}]
ListB=[{"id=2","name="xyz"}, {"id=1, "name"="mno"}]
Should return [{"id"=1,"name="abc"},{"id=1, "name"="def"}] because id =1 exists in listB and the count of id with value 1 in listA is more then 1.
Eg 2:
ListA=[{"id"=2,"name="abc"},{"id=1, "name"="def"}]
ListB=[{"id=1","name="xyz"}, {"id=1, "name"="mno"}]


should return {"id=1, "name"="def"} because common id in both list is 1 and the count of id with value 1 in ListB is more then 1.
```

Comment: Could a scenario be `ListA=[{"id"=1, "name="abc"}, {"id"=1, "name"="def"}, {"id"=2, "name"="ghi"}]` and `ListB=[{"id"=2, "name="xyz"}, {"id"=2, "name"="jkl"}, {"id"=1, "name"="mno"}]`? If yes, would you then expect `[{"id"=1, "name="abc"}, {"id"=1, "name"="def"}, {"id"=2, "name="xyz"}, {"id"=2, "name"="jkl"}]` as output?

Comment: it only has to select the value from List A. so here the output would be as [{"id"=1, "name="abc"}, {"id"=1, "name"="def"}, {"id"=2, "name"="ghi"}] as the counter of id=1 is more then 1 in listA and id=2 is more then 1 in list B and the ids are in common.

Comment: Uhm, okay, I find that a bit confusing. Does that mean you always want your output to be from _either_ `ListA` _or_ `ListB`, never from both, even when both lists fulfill the requirements of returning items to the output?

Comment: @AstridE. I want the output only from ListA, ListB is just used for comparison. If ListB has the same Id of ListA and that Id exists more than 1 in ListB, I want to get all elements of the same Id from ListA, likewise, if that Id exists more than 1 in listA and also has the same Id in List B, I want to get all elements of the same Id from List A.

Comment: return from ListA if Id count is more than 1 in list A or list B, and that Id has to be common to both the list. if both the list has id count that is equal to 1, I don't want to return anything.

Comment: I don't see how that specification matches with your second example in your question post, where you _do_ return items from `ListB`?

Comment: I have updated the examples.

Comment: Yes, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain this is the best solution, but as far as I've understood the question, it should be *a* solution.

Assuming you have an `Item` class as follows:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and define `itemsA` and `itemsB` as `List<Item>`s, you can first find all `Id`s that are present in both lists, then select the applicable items from `itemsA` based on occurrence of each `Id` in either list:

```
IEnumerable<int> idsInBothItemLists = itemsA
    .Select(a => a.Id)
    .Intersect(itemsB.Select(b => b.Id))
    .Distinct();

List<Item> items = itemsA
    .Where(a => idsInBothItemLists.Contains(a.Id))
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .Where(gr => 
        gr.Skip(1).Any() ||
        itemsB.Where(b => b.Id == gr.Key).Skip(1).Any())
    .SelectMany(gr => gr.Select(item => item))
    .ToList();
```

(`.Skip(1).Any()` serves the same purpose as `.Count() > 1` in your original code; it simply checks whether there are any items left after skipping the first item.)

---

Printing the output from the suggested population of `itemsA` and `itemsB`

```
foreach (var entry in items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.Id + " " + entry.Name);
}
```

e.g. for input

```
var itemsA = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "abc" },
    new Item { Id = 3, Name = "def" },
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "ghi" },
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "jkl" }
};

var itemsB = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "xyz" },
    new Item { Id = 2, Name = "jkl" },
    new Item { Id = 1, Name = "mno" },
    new Item { Id = 3, Name = "pqr" }
};
```

gives

> 1 abc
> 1 ghi
> 2 jkl